# How can I remove metadata from a JPEG image in Java?

Tags: java, metadata, jpeg

I'm trying to remove metadata from a .jpg file and replace it with nothing. Can anyone provide an example of how I might do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062959/how-to-remove-image-metadata-from-large-images-without-out-of-memory-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Metadata isn't read when you read in the image. So just read it in and write it back.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
```

Comment: That is the whole program. Just replace "image.jpg" with the file name.

Comment: What about keep the image quality?

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot about lossy compression... That's a great point. Perhaps this is a little more difficult than at first glance. I think you might be stuck with reading in the image as a byte stream and manually stripping the metadata...

Answer (score 3):

The Apache [ExifRewriter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/imaging/formats/jpeg/exif/ExifRewriter.html):

> Reads a Jpeg image, removes all EXIF metadata (by removing the APP1 segment), and writes the result to a stream.

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/photo.jpg"));
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/photo_without.jpg"))) 

new ExifRewriter().removeExifMetadata(is, os);
```