# How can I remove metadata from an image (JPG) without losing quality?

Tags: java, image, metadata, jpeg, image-compression

I already found this nearly similar question on Stackoverflow:

[How can I remove metadata from a JPEG image in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666999/how-can-i-remove-metadata-from-a-jpeg-image-in-java)

But when I use the Method described above, the saved image is being compressed. Is there any way to remove the metadata without compressing the image? Is there any library that I could use in my Java-Program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finaly found a solution by using Apache "commons-imaging":

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/imaging/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/examples/WriteExifMetadataExample.java

```
    public void removeExifMetadata(final File jpegImageFile, final File dst)
        throws IOException, ImageReadException, ImageWriteException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        os = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

        new ExifRewriter().removeExifMetadata(jpegImageFile, os);
    } finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```